# device doesn't support the MFMail composer sheet

Tags: iphone, mfmailcomposer

I have an app where I want to send mail.I have a button where it directs to the MailComposer sheet,It works pretty well in my simulator but can't send the mail so I need to use the device my problem was every time I clicked the button to direct it's mail composer the device doesn't support the MFMailComposer sheet, the device that I was using was a 3G iphone.

Comment: Which iOS version has your phone? Also is it configured for sending mail (i.e. have you set up at least one mail account in your phone Mail settings) ?

Comment: Pretty well! It works after I set up one mail account, it was an iOS version 5.0.1. Thank You Mr.Lefteris!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if the device has at least one mail account added.

Comment: this question has already been a year ago & already been solved but still thanks for your courage in answering it! A check for you ;)